# XSLT for-each ->how to return result only in one element

Tags: xslt, foreach, xslt-1.0

I have for each part in my XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Engineers/Value">
<wor1:Engineer><xsl:value-of select="Name"/>;</wor1:Engineer>
</xsl:for-each>
```

and my output is like this (in case when result returns 3 elements)

```
<wor1:Engineer>John;</wor1:Engineer>
<wor1:Engineer>Susan;</wor1:Engineer>
<wor1:Engineer>Bob;</wor1:Engineer>
```

But I want result like this only in ONE row:

```
 <wor1:Engineer>John;Susan;Bob;</wor1:Engineer>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<wor1:Engineer>
  <xsl:for-each select="Engineers/Value">
    <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
</wor1:Engineer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in XSLT 3.0

```
<wor1:Engineer>{Engineers/Value!(Name||';')}</wor1:Engineer>
```

Comment: This somehow begs the question which, according to the tags, asked for an XSLT 1.0 solution. Furthermore, for the time being XSLT 3.0 isn't even final, but rather is a W3C Candidate Recommendation. And I am not aware of any freely available XSLT processor implementing the new spec. The only processor I know of being capable of handling the new version of XSLT 3.0 is the commercial Saxon-EE. That said, this might mature and may one day become a viable answer.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention it, since some projects cost $20 per line of code, that when you're ready to move forward, here's a quick way of saving $100.